# Json array can not be converted to json object

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to send request to server and get response from server,but when i run my application it crash and shows json array can not converted to json object..the following is my code and web service..

Response:

```
[
  {
        "id":"15","name":"",
         "contact":"",
          "email":"",
           "comp_name":"Tailor",
            "upload_dir":""
   },
    {
        "id":"16","name":"",
         "contact":"",
          "email":"",
           "comp_name":"Trailor",
            "upload_dir":""
   },
]
```

MainActivity.java

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
     JSONObject json;

       JSONArray searchresult=null;

 class searchs extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        boolean failure = false;
        JSONObject jobj;
        String resultname;
         String match_Detail_id;
         String Names;
         String Ages;
         String Locations;
         String Images;
         String Casts;
         String Profiles;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Processing..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
           // pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress));
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
            //Check for success tag
            //int success;
            Looper.prepare();

            String language=splang.getText().toString();
            String religion = sprelg.getText().toString();
            String marriage=spmrgstatus.getText().toString();
            String contri=spcountry.getText().toString();
            String states=spstate.getText().toString();
            String city=spcity.getText().toString();

            System.out.println("Lang : " + language);
            System.out.println("REligions : " + religion);
            System.out.println("Maritals : " + marriage);
            System.out.println("Countrys : " + contri);
            System.out.println("States : " + states);
            System.out.println("Citys : " + city);

             try {
                 //Building Parameters

                 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_id", language));
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subcat_id", religion));
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", marriage));
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", contri));
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", states));


                 Log.d("request!", "starting");
                 // getting product details by making HTTP request
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                     SEARCH_URL, "POST", params);

                 //check your log for json response
                 Log.d("Request attempt", json.toString());


                 //final String str = json.toString();

                // jobj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                // final String msg = jobj.getString("searchresult");

                 searchresult = new JSONArray(json.toString());
                 for (int i = 0; i <searchresult.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject c = searchresult.getJSONObject(i);

                     match_Detail_id = c.getString("id");
                     Log.d("Request attempt", match_Detail_id);
                     Names = c.getString("name");
                     Log.d("Request name", Names);
                     Profiles = c.getString("contact");
                     Log.d("Request profile", Profiles);
                     Images = c.getString("upload_dir");
                     Log.d("Request image", Images);
                     Casts = c.getString("email");
                     Log.d("Request cast", Casts);
                     Ages = c.getString("comp_name");
                     Log.d("Request age", Ages);



                     HashMap<String, String> hmp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                     hmp.put(TAG_AGE, Ages+" years");
                     hmp.put(TAG_CAST, Casts);
                     hmp.put(TAG_IMAGE, Images);

                     hmp.put(TAG_MATCH_ID, match_Detail_id);
                     hmp.put(TAG_NAME, Names);
                     hmp.put(TAG_PROFILE, Profiles);

                     alhmp.add(hmp);


                     //String age_fromc = c.getString("age_from");
                 }

                /* runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() 
                 {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {

                        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchResults.class);
                        intent.putExtra("match_data", alhmp);
                        //intent.putExtra("id", strtext);
                        intent.putExtra("prmatch_id", match_Detail_id);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } 
                });*/


                 }catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return null;
        }
        // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
             pDialog.dismiss();


             alhmp.clear();


                splang.setText("Select");
                sprelg.setText("Select");

                spmrgstatus.setText("Select");
                spcountry.setText("Select Country");
                spstate.setText("Select State");
                spcity.setText("Select City");
                /*if(searchresult == null || searchresult.length() == 0){


                    Intent inss=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchResults.class);
                    inss.putExtra("match_data", alhmp);
                    //inss.putExtra("id", strtext);
                    inss.putExtra("prmatch_id", match_Detail_id);
                    startActivity(inss);

                }*/

    }}
```

JSONParser

```
   public class JSONParser {

 static InputStream is = null;
  static JSONObject jObj = null;
  static String json = "";
  static JSONArray jsonarry=null;
  // constructor
  public JSONParser() {
  }

  // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
  public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
          List<NameValuePair> params) {

      // Making HTTP request
      try {
        // check for request method
          if(method.equals("POST")){
              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
              httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
              HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
             is = httpEntity.getContent();
          } else if(method.equals("GET")) {
              //request method is GET
              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
              url += "?" + paramString;
              HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
              HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
              is = httpEntity.getContent();
          }
      }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace ();
      }catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      try {
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line = null;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line + "\n");
          }
          is.close();
          json = sb.toString();
          Log.d("Request attempt","JSON >>>" +  json.toString());
          } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
          }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
      try { jObj = new JSONObject(json);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
          Log.e("JSON PArser", "Error Parsing data" + e.toString());
      }
      return jObj;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your Json String:

```
{ "record": [
     {
        "id":"15","name":"",
         "contact":"",
          "email":"",
           "comp_name":"Tailor",
            "upload_dir":""
     },
     {
        "id":"16","name":"",
         "contact":"",
          "email":"",
           "comp_name":"Trailor",
            "upload_dir":""
    }
  ]
}
```

Use [this site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to check your structure.

Comment: why cant i use my response as i created,,you added record as key

Comment: How is your target class named where you assign the parser results to? Check the tool: if you omit the _record_ (class _Record_) they use _Example_ as class. In addition, there was a comma too much.

Comment: i accept and vote up..yeah as you said to give key to my array was working..but the answer what i want is regarding to response as give in my question..any idea?

Comment: What exception do you get? Hard to figure out without a hint. But from what I can see so far, I'd say you should first parse the JSON String into a JSONObject `jObj = new JSONObject(json);` (you actually did this already) and then fetch the JSON array from that object: `searchresult = jObj.JSONArray("record");` (here put in the name instead of the JSON String); you can find the same in this example (section _Parsing JSON Data_):http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: i said with key of json array i am able to access..but see in my question i have given reposnse without key,,so what if i want to access in that way?

Comment: To be honest: I've no idea; if the key can't be added by the sender, you could add it yourself, e.g `jsonString = "{\"record\": " + jsonString + "}";`

Answer (score 1):

Change `jObj` in  `jObj = new JSONObject(json);` as JSONArray.

The `jsonparser` class your using always get the response as JSONObject, you have to check the response is JSONObject or JSONArray then convert it and return it to your main class..

**EDIT**

Your response an `JSONArray` do you know that?  Check your JSONParser class you are getting the response there as `json = sb.toString();`. Then you are convert it as JSONObject like `jObj = new JSONObject(json);`, So it will show the error. You must get it as `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);`, because your response is an JSONArray.

Comment: you mean to say i need to change my web service?

Comment: No, your response as array, so you have to get it as array in parser class.

Comment: how can i get it..can you define answer

Comment: yes its working fine now..but problem is image is not displaying..it display ic_launcher image...

Answer (score 1):

You could try and change this line:

```
searchresult = new JSONArray(json.toString());
```

to this line:

```
searchresult = json.getJSONArray(0);
```

But you should always add a key to the JSON String (like Trinimon suggested) and use:

```
searchresult = json.getJSONArray(KEY_VALUE); // in Tinimon's example "record"
```

to have your JSON Array.

Comment: thanks it works..but as per my response how can i access?i vote up